# Getting output parameter from stored procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, php-mssql

I'm trying to get the stored procedure to fire and return the output parameter as well as the result set. Currently I just get the result set array with a balnk variable where the output parameter should be.

```
//initiate function
    $proc = mssql_init('usp_Web_Return_Installer_Details', $msdb); 

    $enrolledScopes = '';

    mssql_bind($proc, '@InstallerID', $_SESSION['user']['Installer_ID'], SQLINT4, false, false, 10);

    mssql_bind($proc, '@EnrolledScopes', &$enrolledScopes, SQLVARCHAR, true, true, 5000); 

    //Execute Procedure 
    $result = mssql_execute($proc); 

    do {
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $results[] = $row;    
        }
    } while (mssql_next_result($result));

    //Free Memory 
    mssql_free_statement($proc); 

    print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `mssql_bind` for your output parameter from storedprocedure

```
mssql_bind($stmt, "@outParam", &$outParam, true)
```

So, `$outParam` is your result.

Comment: That's what this line should be doing:
mssql_bind($proc, '@EnrolledScopes', &$enrolledScopes, SQLVARCHAR, true, true, 5000);

Comment: Yes. So, the result should be `$enrolledScopes`

Comment: Yeah that's what i'm saying, the array $result returns expected content but $enrolledScopes is blank

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it from your code :D
[Please check the php bugs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=21089), it may be the problem

Comment: I did see that  but didnt know if anyone knew a workaround. That bug is very old too